# Delete schemaLocation of an XML

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML and I want to be able to edit a value with PHP, all the XML that I receive and upload to my database bring in xsi:schemaLocation inside the Comprobante this node

> http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4
> http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd

However, some that have addenda bring more links which I want to eliminate and leave only what I put above.

I give you an example an XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.walmartmexico.com.mx http://www.walmartmexico.com.mx/AddendaKioscos.xsd" Version="4.0"  Fecha="2023-04-20T16:23:57" Moneda="MXN" TipoCambio="1" SubTotal="2074.12" Descuento="46.62" Total="2351.90" FormaPago="04" CondicionesDePago="Inmediato" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="03310" NoCertificado="" Exportacion="01" Serie="ICABM" Folio="" Sello="" xmlns:otro="http://www.walmartmexico.com.mx">
  <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="NWM9709244W4" Nombre="NUEVA WAL MART DE MEXICO" RegimenFiscal="601" />
  <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XXXXXX" Nombre="XXXX" UsoCFDI="G03" DomicilioFiscalReceptor="03100" RegimenFiscalReceptor="601" />
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

The value that I want to edit inside the Comprobante is this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.walmartmexico.com.mx http://www.walmartmexico.com.mx/AddendaKioscos.xsd"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using cfdiUtils, I leave my code in case anyone is interested:

```
    $docxml =file_get_contents('XML PATH');

    $cleaner = new Cleaner($docxml);
    $cleaner->removeAddenda();
    $cleaner->removeNonSatNSschemaLocations();
    $content = $cleaner->retrieveXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the XML using DOM. In DOM anything is a node. This includes attributes. `xsi:schemaLocation` is an attribute node inside a namespace, the XML parser will resolve it to `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation` using the value from the `xmlns:xsi` namespace definition.

```php
// bootstrap the XML
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
// access the attribute node ...
$attribute = $document
  // ... on the document element (the "root" element) ...
  ->documentElement
  // ... using the namespace aware method (suffix "*NS")
  ->getAttributeNodeNS(
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'schemaLocation'
  );
  
// read attribute value
$schemaLocation = $attribute->value;

// edit value
$urls = array_diff(
    explode(' ', $schemaLocation),
    [
      'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4'
    ]
);

// write new attribute value
$attribute->textContent = implode(' ', $urls);
  
echo $document->saveXML();
```